# executing a function in the inferior process, and getting the returned result to python

Tags: python, gdb, gdb-python

As mentioned in a previous question ([How to examine a gdb.Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66271423/how-to-examine-a-gdb-type)) I'm writing some specialized gdb scripting in python.

I want to call a function pointer, obtained from the inferior process, on a value, also obtained from the inferior process, and get the returned result as a gdb.Value.  How?

One possibility is to convert everything to strings and convenience variables, then use gdb.execute() to perform a CLI print command, (e.g. p $2($1) ) which will make a new convenience variable, then get the convenience variable.  This seems roundabout and error-prone.  Is there a better way?

Comment: If you have a function gdb.Value of type `TYPE_CODE_FUNC` named `f`, a gdb.Value you want to use as argument named `a`, and want the result in `r`, then try `r=f(a)`.

Comment: Thank you.  This didn't work for me, but now I know why.  My gdb.Value has type gdb.TYPE_CODE_TYPEDEF.  After
`fcn = fcn.cast(fcn.type.strip_typedefs()).dereference()`
I'm good.